# Tons of problems launching the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, haxm

First things first, I have 64-bit Windows 8.1 home edition and have an AMD processor.

I've been trying to get the emulator working for days, but every time I think I find a solution or a past question/answer on here that will help me, it doesn't work.

It'll be a multiple step solution, and then one step won't work and to fix that step I need to follow 5 more steps, and then one of those steps doesn't work and it just goes on and on until eventually I have no idea what's going on and I'm back at square 1.

---

**Issue #1: The initial error message**

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I figured out how to solve this from looking at other questions on here. I go into my SDK manager, check the box, etc. I know what to do. I now go to my SDK folder to finish the final step by double clicking the .exe to install the Intel HAXM, but I get another error.

**Issue #2: Can't install the Intel HAXM**

Error message:

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

Okay, so this is just another thing I'll look up how to fix and I'll be good to go, right?

Nope. Here is where I'm stuck... everything I've tried doesn't work.

**Attempt #1: Enabling virtualization in BIOS**

Past answers have said that I'm supposed to go into my BIOS and enable virtualization. The issue is that when I go into my BIOS, the option isn't there. I would select to enable it if I saw it as an option to enable... but it's not listed anywhere on my BIOS.

**Attempt #2: Enabling Hyper-V**

I heard another way to solve the problem is to go into "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and tick the box beside Hyper-V. The issue is that I don't have a box for Hyper-V! It's not there!

Upon googling I found out that I probably don't have it because I don't have Windows pro.

**Where I am now/My questions for you**

Those are the two solutions I've found, and neither seem to work. I don't know what to do at this point.

- Is there another path I can take to run the emulator, or do I need to install the Intel HAXM no matter what?
- Are there any other ways to let me install Intel HAXM other than the two things I've tried?
- Am I wrong in what I'm doing to enable virtualization? Should the option be there and I'm just not looking in the right spot? Is there a specific thing I'm not doing in my BIOS menu or my Windows Features menu that is not letting me see these options?

Thank you!! :)

Comment: In my experience it never works if your cpu doesn't support it but you can try to follow this link to try to install hyper-v (http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7.aspx) or just use ARM image.

Comment: @user83676 I can help further with more information. Can we make a chat room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an AMD processor, I think you're looking for AMD-V settings in the BIOS. Contact your PC manufacturer for assistance.

> Is there another path I can take to run the emulator, or do I need to install the Intel HAXM no matter what?

You need HAXM for the x86 emulator on Windows and OS X (and an equivalent bit of tech on Linux). You are welcome to use the ARM emulator images, but they will be slow. You are also welcome to test your app on Android hardware.

> Is there a specific thing I'm not doing in my BIOS menu

Possibly, but you would need to contact your PC manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: Oh whoops I kept thinking I was mis-spelling it, and right-clicked to correct spelling and it changed it to "visualization" each time without me noticing, haha. 



I think I'll go with the ARM image at this point. Is it a difficult process to set up/install/etc.?

Comment: @user83676: You just have to download the images as part of setting up your AVDs in the AVD Manager. It works out of the box otherwise. However, perhaps I didn't explain sufficiently the performance characteristics of the ARM emulator. Glaciers might be faster. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare information on visualization vs. virtualization not neede anymore.